# Never seen before C++ for loop

Tags: c#, c++, for-loop

I was converting a C++ algorithm to C#.
I came across this for loop:

```
for (u = b.size(), v = b.back(); u--; v = p[v]) 
b[u] = v;
```

It gives no error in C++, but it does in C# (cannot convert int to bool).
I really can't figure out this for loop, where is the condition?

Can someone please explain?

*PS. Just to check, to adapt a VECTOR to a LIST does
    b.back()
correspond to
    b[b.Count-1]
?*

Comment: Where is the condition? That would be `u--`. The semi-colons are used to delimit the various parts of the `for` statement.

Comment: This is quite a normal loop. C# doesn't convert numbers to bools implicitly so you need to turn the condition into `; u-- != 0; `

Comment: As to your P.S., that would perform correctly, but you can also use the Linq extension method Last(), which is synonymous with vector::back() (and would work with virtually any IEnumerable, not just a List). vector::size() could either be List.Count or IEnumerable.Count() (when you know it's a List, both perform identically, but again the method is available for any IEnumerable)

Comment: for( `variable list`, as long as `condition`, do `whatever list`) { do this too }

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `p` anyway?  I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write this, but the incremental code `v = p[v]` is driving me nuts.  The `v` looks like the value of items in `b`, but `p` 's relationship is puzzling.

Comment: If the syntax confuses 33 people enough to vote +1, then the syntax must be problematic somehow. It used to be extremely common for string manipulation, neat looking things like termChar(s){while(*(s++));return s}, but with C being the base syntax for higher-level languages like Objective C, you're simply going to have more people confused by the "basics", so it's a good question to have available to google.

Comment: @BillK: I was also very confused why people are saying this is bad code, if you go read K&R or any old C programming books this usage is quite common.

Comment: @Jessie Good--Good code has nothing to do with what is allowable in the language, it has to do with how long it takes an unacquanted co-worker to read the code.  If it causes any kind of confusion, it's not the best possible solution, even if it's legal.  Often a more verbose solution is Much better than a terse one, and most compilers will compile to the same thing either way.

Comment: I hope that, after converting the code, you give the variables better names than `b`, `u`, `v`, etc. The only reason they were named this way is because someone wanted to look smart by making their code unreadable.

Comment: @Michael: I upvoted the question because it shows research effort; it is useful and clear. Not because I "don't ever understand a for-loop". (In fact, I gave an answer.) The main reason why I think this question is useful is that it demonstrates a case of unnecessarily unreadable code.

Comment: If the original coder found u-- in that condition to be the best option, I can understand that, but that's where a little inline documentation would go a long way. `//decrement u until it reaches 0`

Comment: @Michael http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/ We're here to help everyone, even beginners.

Comment: @houbysoft: this is a general stackoverflow problem. If you ask a very detailed, well researched and interesting question in a specific research domain, which leads to a solution to a hard and interesting problem, and you answer such a question after a hard days worth of research, you will get only a few dozen visitors and one or two upvotes from a few experts in the field. If you want to gain a lot of rep quickly, you have to ask and answer questions like these. "How do I add two numbers in php", "what does `do` mean in C++" - will get thousands of hits from beginners looking for a tutorial.

Comment: If this is a “normal” loop (as in, a loop that you’d usually write) then I’m a horse.

Comment: @vsz I agree with your comment, only that I would substitute "fact" for "problem".

Comment: @DanielDaranas Agreed. A Q&A system is designed to answer questions, not show how incredibly smart a programmer you are.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding your PS, in C# I'd use `theList.Last()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775)

Comment: I think quite a few people have missed the point that the questioner is a C# programmer who has comes across a C++ loop that he didn't understand because it's not a legal C# loop. He's not a bad programmer, he's a programmer who's having to deal with a language he's not familiar with.

Comment: @Chris This would be dangerous, since he don't know some behaviours of C++ and may get bugs which are hard to track in his translated code. I'd rather spend a few days learning C++ basics than spend my life struggling with buggy algorithm codes.

Comment: @Ray That was my point. He *is* trying to learn the basics, he just chose to do so by asking a question here. If you think he'd be better off picking up a 'Learn C++ Basics' book or something, that's fair enough, but my problem was more with the people who are saying what amounts to "you don't know how a for-loop works? You're BAD" and getting upvoted for it. As someone else said, an elementary question is not a bad question.

Comment: these kind of codes, questions your knowledge even on basics. good practice.

Comment: Why would you want to set v to the same value each iteration? I don't get the logic here.

Comment: @Mike `v` is set to a value that depends on its previous value, not to the same value. It's no different than, say, `p = p->next`.

Comment: @BillK you thesis about good code holds true not for all situations and not for all languages. C++ community (or at least a big part of C++ development community, the guys that implement new features for the language, write books on it, etc.) considers such loops elegant and easily understandable. It's a matter of habit, experience and your favorite language.
P.s. Also I consider this kind of loops elegant. But at the same time I prefer verbose C# code (because language is different and is targeted at different developers/tasks).

Answer (score 321, accepted):

The condition of the `for` loop is in the middle - between the two semicolons `;`.

In C++ it is OK to put almost any expression as a condition: anything that evaluates to zero means `false`; non-zero means `true`.

In your case, the condition is `u--`: when you convert to C#, simply add `!= 0`:

```
for (u = b.size(), v = b.back(); u-- != 0; v = p[v]) 
    b[u] = v; //                     ^^^^ HERE
```

Comment: By the way, Thomas may have been confused by the use of the comma too, it's very different than the semi-colon, it lets you do multiple things in one section of the for loop (in this case, it initialized two variables).  Last time I checked these unusual constructs weren't considered the most readable solution possible and may therefore be frowned-upon by some.

Comment: If I remember correctly, and expression containing a comma has the value of the last subexpression on the right. This comes from C and can be used in any expression, not only in a for loop.

Comment: @Roger This wouldn't be the same loop since you are decrementing u at the end of the loop, instead of the beginning (i.e. after b[u] = v instead of before). In fact you would need to initialize it with `u = b.size() - 1` instead.

Comment: Fyi: I just pushed you over the 500K limit. Is that like being the one millionth customer somewhere and winning somethin? In any case: many congratulations; always looking up to your precise, sharp answers! Keep going; meet you making the 1 million thing ... later this century.

Answer (score 166):

Lots of accurate answers, but I think it's worth writing out the equivalent while loop.

```
for (u = b.size(), v = b.back(); u--; v = p[v]) 
   b[u] = v;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
u = b.size();
v = b.back();
while(u--) {
   b[u] = v;
   v = p[v];
}
```

You might consider refactoring to the while() format as you translate to C#. In my opinion it is clearer, less of a trap for new programmers, and equally efficient.

As others have pointed out -- but to make my answer complete -- to make it work in C# you would need to change `while(u--)` to `while(u-- != 0)`.

... or `while(u-- >0)` just in case u starts off negative. (OK, `b.size()` will never be negative -- but consider a general case where perhaps something else initialised u).

Or, to make it even clearer:

```
u = b.size();
v = b.back();
while(u>0) {
   u--;
   b[u] = v;
   v = p[v];
}
```

It's better to be clear than to be terse.

Comment: This answer not only clarifies the bad code but also gives a good alternative. 1 up!!

Comment: As an aside, I'd be careful with the `while (u-- >0)` form.  If the spacing gets messed up, you might end up with a "down to zero" loop:  `while (u --> 0)`, which tends to confuse everyone at first glance.  (_I'm not sure if it's valid C#, but it is in C, and I think it may be as well in C++?_)

Comment: I don't think your code is necessarily clearer. The point of `for` instead of `while` is precisely that you put the initialization and the increment/decrement in one statement, and that doesn't necessarily make the code harder to understand. Otherwise, we shouldn't be using `for` at all.

Comment: you might also want to put the whole thing in braces, so that no name conflicts can occur

Comment: Wouldn't first while loop run one iteration more than second since post decrement is used? I.e. if b.size() equals 1 the first will run once while second loop won't run at all.

Comment: It's also important to rewrite as little code as possible. (The for loop could change, after all.) You've put "u--" in two separate places, and the loop isn't really clearer (I can see what the for loop does in one glance; I have to scan with multiple lines). Being terse has benefits too. Don't downplay them. Still though, a good example of how else it could be written. It does make it easier to understand for anyone who's not used to for statements in C++ (or maybe even at all).

Comment: The last version is wrong though: it should be `while (u>=0)` instead (otherwise you will never process the first element of the list)

Comment: I won't upvote because of "... or while(u-- >0) just in case u starts off negative." While this might work, it's motivated by wrong assumptions.  If `u` starts off negative, `u--` will never be zero or positive. Signed integer overflow has undefined behaviour in C++.

Comment: wouldn't this be much easier to read written as: `for (u = b.size() - 1, b.back(); u > 0; u--, v = p[v])`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes While of course you'd need to understand the algorithm and the semantics of the variables to know, I made the assumption that if u starts negative, then the loop should execute zero times. We don't know what u's type is. It's only advice, and the right answer will of course come out in unit tests.

Comment: @DidierL: I reverted your suggestion because it's wrong.  Think again, carefully, about the difference between "size" and the last index.

Comment: @Ben this was thought carefully… but before an edit from Dave which slim didn't see while applying my proposed change ;-) The current version is indeed also correct.

Comment: @DidierL: Ok, as a change targeted at revision 2 your comment makes sense.

Comment: @Izkata: Why are you afraid of the "down to zero" loop?  This is one already, regardless of spacing.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not afraid of it, but the intent of my comment was that `-->` isn't normally an operator.  If you haven't seen that spacing before, it can be confusing (and even once you have, it can still causes you to pause, especially if there's spaces around those characters).  It also gives the impression it might be a "go towards zero" operator, which I believe is possible to create in C++ with operator overloading?

Comment: @Izkata: It isn't EVER an operator, it's parsed as a `--` token followed by a `>` token.  Two separate operators.  A "down to zero" loop is just a straightforward combination of post-decrement and greater-than.  C++ operator overloading doesn't create new operators, it just repurposes existing ones.

Comment: @AaronMiller You could put my while loop all on one line if it helps you. (But don't). The original for loop here is a trap for the unwary because it has its increment in the continue condition position, and something that's not a simple increment in the increment position. I say, only use for() if you're going to use it conventionally. Or in obfuscation contests.

Comment: @slim It's really not hard to understand what the for loop is doing. It's usually more difficult to understand why a particular loop is there, but that's true for anything. (e.g., "why count backwards here?" Or "why are these elements being enumerated while these ones aren't?" Or "Where'd this number come from?" etc. Turning the for loop into a while loop probably won't help there. Still, some people prefer different styles of loops. As long as it doesn't extend past my 80 character margin, I could care less how it's structured. :)

Comment: Thinking that this is better code is like thinking that "Dick and Jane" is good writing ... "Dick and Jane" is only more understandable to people not very familiar with the language, but is painful for those who are.

Answer (score 66):

The condition is `u--;`, because it is in the second position of the **for** instruction.

If the value of `u--;` is different from 0, it will be interpreted as `true` (i.e., implicitly casted to the boolean value `true`). If, instead, its value is 0, it will be casted to `false`.

This is [very bad code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738939/never-seen-before-c-for-loop/11738987#comment15587737_11738987).

**Update:** I discussed the writing of "for" loops in this [blog post](http://thedeepbluecpp.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/guideline-5-for-loops-should-be-simple.html). Its recommendations can be summarized in the following paragraphs:

> A for loop is a practical, readable (once you get used to it) and
>   terse construct, but you need to use it well. Because of its uncommon
>   syntax, using it in a too imaginative way is not a good idea.
>
> All parts of the for loop should be short and readable. Variable names
>   should be chosen to make it easy to understand.

This example clearly violates these recomendations.

Comment: Resulting in an infinite loop?

Comment: Or it will stop at u == 0 probably...?

Comment: No; in C++ there's an implicit conversion from int to bool, with 0 converting to false. The loop will terminate when u-- == 0. In C#, there's no such implicit conversion so you'd have to explicitly say u-- == 0. EDIT: This is in response to your first comment.

Comment: @Thomas: The loop is not (necessarily) infinite. The value of _u_ is decremented each time it is evaluated. When u is 0, u-- will evaluate to 0, so the loop will be stopped (and _u_ further decremented, of course, for a final value of -1).

Comment: This is *terrible* code, for one very simple reason; you could not easily comprehend it when you read it. It's "clever", a "hack"; it makes use of a combination of coding structures, and knowledge of how they work behind the scenes, to create a structure that does the job but that defies understanding, because it's not in the form that the language authors envisioned and that was communicated to most language users.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd +1 it... if not the "This is very bad code." statement ;)

Comment: I don't understand why so many people seem to think **u--** is really bad code simply because of the missing (implicit in C++) **!= 0**. Surely anyone working with code will be perfectly aware that *0=false, every other value=true*. There's far more scope for confusion regarding pre-/post-incrementing of **u**, or people perhaps assuming that **u = b.size()** will *always* execute before **v = b.back()** (my understanding is the execution sequence there is undefined, but I stand to be corrected).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The implicit cast alone (although I despise it) is not the only reason, nor the main one. I agree with you in that the pre-/post-incrementing potential confusion is far more important. The combination of two statements in the initialization part just adds to it, and the overall result is very unreadable, way beyond my personal tolerance for hard to maintain code - which is very small, indeed, but for good reasons and after years of experience as a developer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The execution sequence is well defined in the C++ standard. `u = b.size() ` will always execute first.

Comment: @Jesse Good: Ah. Well you sound pretty definite about that, so I'm sure it's true. Perhaps I was thinking of standard C - or maybe the execution sequence of passed params in something like **foobar(foo1(),foo2());** If I wrote that I wouldn't assume foo1() would always execute before foo2() (but either I'm wrong again, or that's a different "kind" of comma! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it's a different kind of comma. The comma which separates arguments of a function is not the comma operator. If I recall well, the former (a *comma separator* - see the comment below) gives room for unspecified order of evaluation, while the latter does not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The first example is a **comma operator**, the second is a **comma separator**.

Comment: @Jesse Good,Daniel Daranas: I've learnt something already, thanks guys! I actually had this vague idea that commas might be used instead of semicolons to group statements where execution order didn't matter, so a combination of smart compiler and multi-processor platform could save time by executing them in parallel. It *could* have been a good idea, but it obviously wouldn't fly now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A smart compiler doesn't need commas in order to figure out what can be done in parallel. It analyzes the dependencies among the statements. Anyway, C and C++ do have commas that mean "unspecified evaluation order". They are not the comma operator commas, but rather the commas that separate arguments in function calls.

Comment: I don't think this is bad code, let alone very bad. It's perfectly clear, written in common, traditional patterns.

Comment: @Kaz: Thinking about it, I suppose by implication you could "hint" to the compiler that several instructions can be executed in parallel simply by framing them as parameters to a dummy function. But it's not a bulletproof principle. Just because it makes no difference whether foo1() or foo2() is executed first, that doesn't prove they don't both call something that can't execute concurrently.

Comment: The best hint to a modern compiler that things can be done in parallel is to not have any data dependencies between them. This means that we have statements `S1 ; S2` and `S2` does not evaluate any operands which are modified by `S1`, and `S1` and `S2` do not have any external effects (since these have to be ordered). There is no need to screw up a language with undefined evaluation orders. That only creates programmer pitfalls.

Comment: A nice parallel evaluation construct would work like this: all operands enclosed in the construct refer to their prior values. So for example if we had `a = b` and `b = a` in parallel, the effect would be that `a` and `b` are swapped. Not that the behavior is undefined. That is to say, the behavior would be as if all operands are copied into temporary locations, so that the assignments do not interfere with the evaluations.

Answer (score 23):

This will be the C# form of your loop.

```
// back fetches the last element of vector in c++.
for (u = b.size(), v = b.back(); (u--) != 0; v = p[v]) 
{      
  b[u] = v;      
}
```

Just replace equivalent for size() and back().

What it does is reverses the list and stores in an array.
But in C# we directly have system defined function for this. So you don't need to write this loop also.

```
b = b.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: by taking `v = b.back();` out of the for intializer didn't you just change the way it works, since the `v = p[v]` is overridden by

Comment: v = p[v] will not have any effect on final result as this line will execute at the last. And after that v is not referred in the loop. This line is there just to show how the loop is converted from c++ to C#.

Comment: in the c++ code `v = b.back();` was executed once before the iterations started and `v = p[v]` was executed at the beginning of each iteration. In that C# version `v = p[v]` is still executed at the beginning of each iteration but `v = b.back();` is executed right after it, changing the value of `v` for the next instruction `b[u] = v;`. (maybe the question was edited after you read it)

Comment: @Rain The issue is `v = b.back()`.  You have it executing at every loop iteration instead of just the first one - we don't know what `back()` does (are there any side-effects?  Does it change the internal representation of `b`?), so this loop is _not_ equivalent to the one in the question.

Comment: Please check how loop executes. v = p[v] is the last statement which will execute in the loop.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm

Comment: @Rain Exactly, take a closer look at it yourself.  The _initialization_ step happens only once before the loop begins, _not_ at the beginning of _every iteration_.  Your code would be correct if `v = b.back()` was moved outside the loop, above it.  (Also, if you're trying to respond to someone, use `@` in front of their name, so we get a notification)

Comment: @Rain I made a small mistake in my comment: `v = p[v]` is actually executed in the end of each iteration. But my point was that when it is executed at the end of the first iteration, `v` gets overwritten by the first instruction of the second iteration. Did it make more sense now?

Comment: why `(u--) > 0`, instead of `(u--) != 0`?  The conditions are not identical.  If `u` happens to be negative, the first will evaluate false, while the second will be true.

Answer (score 15):

```
u = b.size(), v = b.back()
```

is initialization.

```
u--
```

is the condition.

```
v = p[v]
```

is the iteration

Answer (score 14):

The condition is the result of `u--`, which is the value of `u` before it was decremented.

In C and C++, an `int` *is* convertible to bool by implicitly doing a `!= 0` comparison (0 is `false`, everything else is `true`).

`b.back()` is the last element in a container, which is `b[b.size() - 1]`, when `size() != 0`.

Answer (score 11):

In C everything non-zero is `true` in "boolean" contexts, such as the loop end condition or a conditional statement. In C# you have to make that check explicit: `u-- != 0`.

Comment: This is not the question of OP. He is asking about the evaluation of the terminal condition (i.e. 'u--' in this case).

Answer (score 6):

As stated by others, the fact that C++ has implicit casting to boolean means the conditional is `u--`, which will be true if the value is non-zero.

It's worth adding, that you've a false assumption in asking "where's the conditional". In both C++ and C# (and other similarly syntaxed languages) you can have an empty conditional. In this case it always evaluates to true, so the loop continues forever, or until some other condition exits it (via `return`, `break`, or `throw`).

```
for(int i = 0; ; ++i)
  doThisForever(i);
```

Indeed, any part of the for statement can be left out, in which case it's just not performed.

In general, `for(A; B; C){D}` or `for(A; B; C)D;` becomes:

```
{A}
loopBack:
if(!(B))
  goto escapeLoop;
{D}
{C}
goto loopBack;
escapeLoop:
```

Any one or more of A, B, C or D can be left out.

As a result of this, some favour `for(;;)`  for infinite loops. I do because while `while(true)` is more popular, I read that as "until truth ends being true", which sounds somewhat apocalyptic compared to my reading `for(;;)`  as "forever".

It's a matter of taste, but since I'm not the only person in the world to like `for(;;)` it's worth knowing what it means.

Answer (score 4):

all the answers are correct :-

for loop can be used in a variety of ways as follows :

```
Single Statement inside For Loop
Multiple Statements inside For Loop
No Statement inside For Loop
Semicolon at the end of For Loop
Multiple Initialization Statement inside For
Missing Initialization in For Loop
Missing Increment/Decrement Statement
Infinite For Loop
Condition with no Conditional Operator.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (u = b.size(), v = b.back(); u--; v = p[v]) 
   b[u] = v;
```

In above code, `u` and `v` are initialized with `b.size()` and `b.back()`.

Every time the condition is checked, it executes decrement statement too i.e. `u--`.

The `for` loop will exit when `u` will become `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The error encountered in C# itself clears the doubt. The for-loop searches for a

> FALSE

condition to terminate. And as we know,

> (BOOL) FALSE = (int) 0

but C# cannot process this on its own unlike as C++. So the condition you are searching for is

> u--

but you have to explicitly give the condition in C# as

> u-- != 0

or

> u-- > 0

But still try to avoid this kind of coding practice. The

> while loop

stated above in answer is one of the most simplified version of your

> for-loop.

Comment: @Downvoter: Downvoting is alright as far as you ain't satisfied by the solution but at the same time, please take time to state the reason, so that the answers could be improved.

Answer (score 3):

If you're used to C / C++ this code isn't so hard to read, though it's pretty terse and not that great of code. So let me explain the parts that are more Cism than anything else. First off the general syntax of a C for loop looks like this:

```
for (<initialization> ; <condition>; <increment>)
{
    <code...>
}
```

The initialization code gets run once. Then the condition gets tested before every loop and lastly the increment gets called after every loop. So in your example you'll find the condition is `u--`

Why does `u--` work as a condition in C and not C#? Because C implicitly converts a lot of things too bools and it can cause trouble. For a number anything that is non-zero is true and zero is false. So it will count down from b.size()-1 to 0. Having the side-effect in the condition is a bit annoying and it would be preferable to put it in the increment part of the for loop, though a lot of C code does this. If I were writing it I would do it more like this:

```
for (u = b.size() - 1, v = b.back(); u>=0; --u) 
{
    b[u] = v;
    v = p[v]
}
```

The reason for this is, to me at least, it's clearer. Each part of the for loop does it's job and nothing else. In the original code the condition was modifying the variable. The increment part was doing something that should be in the code block etc.

The comma operator may be throwing you for a loop also. In C something like `x=1,y=2` looks like one statement as far as the compiler is concerned and fits into the initialization code. It just evaluates each of the parts and returns the value of the last one. So for example:

```
std::cout << "(1,2)=" << (1,2) << std::endl;
```

would print out 2.

Comment: The problem with your rewrite is that if b.size() is unsigned, it will iterate for a very long time. (Also, you're missing a semicolon.) But at least you didn't take the "'Dick and Jane' is good English" approach that so many of the other answers and comments did, lauding absurdly verbose rewrites that are only easier to read by neophytes and other unskilled programmers.