# Playing around with for arguments

Tags: c++

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11738939/2436175).

Suppose we have a non empty `std::vector<T> v;`
is there any difference between

```
for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
///Stuff.
}
```

and:

```
for (int i = v.size(); i--; ) {
///Stuff.
}
```

?

I mean, I wouldn't do that for readability sake, but who knows what could be useful in life...

([Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2ac4ac361ea24a1718b1445788fefdb9-9ac5ce49fb3bb81c20db0c664e0c63a1) just a test to see they are equivalent)

**Edit:** The point is having `i` as index to access backward the vector (in a case where having the index was preferable to having iterators)

**Edit 2:** Out of curiosity: They end up having *slightly* different assembly code. See [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%3Cvector%3E%5Cn%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%5Cn%20%20%5Cnint%20printVector(const%20std%3A%3Avector%3Cint%3E%26%20v)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20for%20(int%20i%20%3D%20v.size()%20-%201%3B%20i%20%3E%3D%200%3B%20i--)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20v%5Bi%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.8%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20%20-O2%20-fomit-frame-pointer%20-march%3Dnative%22%7D%5D%7D) and [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%3Cvector%3E%5Cn%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%5Cn%20%20%5Cnint%20printVector(const%20std%3A%3Avector%3Cint%3E%26%20v)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20for%20(int%20i%20%3D%20v.size()%3B%20i--%3B%20)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20v%5Bi%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.8%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20%20-O2%20-fomit-frame-pointer%20-march%3Dnative%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: 1) Benchmark it see that there is no difference. 2) Compare the generated assembly and verify that there is nothing substantially different.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart There's no need to remove `-1` because the condition is checked before loop entry.

Comment: Did you know you can use reverse_iterators to do the this?

Answer (score 4):

One could think of a `for` loop

```
for (<decl-init> ; <condition> ; <post-adjust>) <body>
```

as a rough equivalent to this `while` loop:

```
<decl-init>;
while (condition) {
    <body>;
    <post-adjust>;
}
```

The biggest difference between the `for` and the rewrite above is the scope of variables declared in the `<decl-init>` block, but this is not important for the analysis below.

Rewriting both loops as a `while` loop gives you this:

```
int i = v.size() - 1;
while ( i >= 0 ) {
    <body>;
    i--;
}
```

vs.

```
int i = v.size(); 
while (i--) {
    <body>;
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is that `i` is decremented before entering the iteration, and the condition is started with `i` greater by `1` than in the first loop. These two adjustments "cancel each other", making your loops equivalent from the technical point of view. Aesthetics is a different thing, though: conditions with side effects are harder to understand than "pure" ones, so the first loop is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

It is a legal way of doing it, but using `i--` as a condition in a for loop is a terrible idea in terms of readability.

The for loop is meant to consist of 3 parts - why make people lives harder?

People who read your code will be happy if you stick to the traditional `for` loop:

```
for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    ///Stuff.
}
```